# Method not pulling in values

Tags: c#, class

The below code does not output the showConnections method.  I am unable to determine why it doesn't seem the variables are being initialized even though there is a connection to the database.  Any input is appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace OpenandCloseConnection
{
  //class
  public class MySqlConnection
{

  SqlConnection mySqlConnection = new SqlConnection();

//constructor
public MySqlConnection(string connectionString)
{
    SqlConnection mySqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    showConnections();  //no values are displayed

}//end constructor

//end method
public void showConnections()
{
    //Connection data          
    Console.WriteLine("mySqlConnection.ConnectionString = " +
      this.mySqlConnection.ConnectionString);
    Console.WriteLine("mySqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout = " +
        this.mySqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout);
    Console.WriteLine("mySqlConnection.Database = " +
        this.mySqlConnection.Database);
    Console.WriteLine("mySqlConnection.DataSource = " +
        this.mySqlConnection.DataSource);
    Console.WriteLine("mySqlConnection.PacketSize = " +
        this.mySqlConnection.PacketSize);
    Console.WriteLine("mySqlConnection.ServerVersion = " +
        this.mySqlConnection.ServerVersion);
    Console.WriteLine("mySqlConnection.State = " +
        this.mySqlConnection.State);
    Console.WriteLine("mySqlConnection.WorksationId = " +
        this.mySqlConnection.WorkstationId);
    Console.WriteLine("TEST");

}//end method



public static void Main()
    {
        string connectionString = "some string"

        SqlConnection mySqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        mySqlConnection.Open();
        //close database
        mySqlConnection.Close();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }//end main
       }//end method


   }//end namespace
```

Comment: you aren't using your class `MySqlConnection`.  You're using the standard `SqlConnection` in your Main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the constructor you are assigning the

```
SqlConnection mySqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
```

into a local Variable inside the Main() Method and not into the class variable. You are using the Class variable to display your values:

Modify your your constructor

```
public MySqlConnection(string connectionString)
{
    this.mySqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    showConnections(); 

}
```

EDIT:

Also Modify your Main() to

```
public static void Main()
{
    string connectionString = "some string"

    MySqlConnectionmySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
.....
```

Edit2: (See comment)

```
 public static void showConnections(SqlConnection sqlConn)
 {
        Console.WriteLine("mySqlConnection.ConnectionString = " +
          sqlConn.ConnectionString);
        Console.WriteLine("mySqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout = " +
            sqlConn.ConnectionTimeout);
        Console.WriteLine("mySqlConnection.Database = " +
            sqlConn.Database);
        Console.WriteLine("mySqlConnection.DataSource = " +
            sqlConn.DataSource);
        Console.WriteLine("mySqlConnection.PacketSize = " +
            sqlConn.PacketSize);
        Console.WriteLine("mySqlConnection.ServerVersion = " +
            sqlConn.ServerVersion);
        Console.WriteLine("mySqlConnection.State = " +
            sqlConn.State);
        Console.WriteLine("mySqlConnection.WorksationId = " +
            sqlConn.WorkstationId);
        Console.WriteLine("TEST");
 }

 public static void Main()
 {
        string connectionString = "some string";

        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        showConnections(sqlConnection);
        sqlConnection.Open();
        //close database
        sqlConnection.Close();
        Console.ReadLine();
 }
```

Comment: I made the edit, unfortunately, still nothing being displayed.  Not really sure why.

Comment: Inside the Main() Method change the SqlConnection mySqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString); to MySqlConnection mySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

Comment: Unfortunately, that might not be an option since then I would lose the open and close methods for connecting to the database.  Is their anyway to inherit those into my class?

Comment: No sorry you cannot inherit from SqlConnection because the clkass is sealed. One solution would be to Impletement the Open() and Close Method so that they call the inner mySqlConnection. however this would not be the best idea. A better Solution would be to pass the connectionstring into your ShowConnections Method an call it after initializing (Edit2).

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much!

However, from a technical standpoint, what exactly is my constructor doing then?

Answer (score 1):

```
SqlConnection mySqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
mySqlConnection.Open();
//close database
mySqlConnection.Close();
```

you're using `SqlConnection mySqlConnection`, you want `MySqlConnection mySqlConnection`.

Of course then your code will break because you haven't defined an `Open` method for your class.  You need to figure out what you're trying to do here.

Comment: is there anyway I can use my class to "inherit" the method `Open`

Comment: Have your class expose a `SqlConnection` property, then open that.  `SqlConnection` is a sealed class so you can't inherit it

Comment: sorry I am new to programming in general, how do you do that?